# Get non-readonly-keys of object

Tags: typescript

I would like to be able to define a type such that it takes only the readonly keys of a type. For instance in the example below:

```js
interface Test {
    readonly a: string;
    b: string;
}

const clearProperties = (propertiesToClear: Array<keyof Test>, onObject: Test): Test => {    
    for (let key in propertiesToClear) {
        onObject[key as keyof Test]  = ""; // error: Cannot assign to 'a' because it is a read-only property.
    }

    return onObject;
}
```

I would like to be able to define a type such that we'd be able to avoid this type of error by only allowing `propertiesToClear`to be specified as a key which can be mutated.

I've seen ways to go the 'other' way, if you catch my meaning - to make readonly properties mutable. But I can't see a way of defining a type of only non-readonly-keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do that, you need to iterate through `Test` and compare each key/value pair with similar mutable pair.

```js
interface Test {
    readonly a: string;
    b: string

}

// credits goes to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-421529650
type IfEquals<T, U, Y = true, N = false> =
    (<G>() => G extends T ? 1 : 2) extends
    (<G>() => G extends U ? 1 : 2) ? Y : N;

type ExtractMutable<T> = {
    [Prop in keyof T]:
    /**
     * Example:
     * IfEquals<{readonly a: string}, Record<'a',string> -> returns false
     */
    IfEquals<Pick<T, Prop>, Record<Prop, T[Prop]>> extends false
    ? never
    : Prop
}[keyof T]

{
    type Check = ExtractMutable<Test> // "b"
}

const clearProperties = (propertiesToClear: Array<ExtractMutable<Test>>, onObject: Test): Test =>
    propertiesToClear.reduce((acc, elem) => ({
        ...acc,
        [elem]: ""
    }), onObject)

clearProperties(['b'], { a: 'a', b: 'b' }) // ok

clearProperties(['a'], { a: 'a', b: 'b' }) // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwLABQyxyUEcAJgPYgA2AnsnAFzJZSgDmA3IScgCNW7LoUIBfMQQD005AjIVgYDMk5VMyMFWQALMGAAOGZrM7LdAVwEA6BFQC20gLLAFVDFRhhpqeoYgAZQVgQx9gDAxLTGkAJgB2AAZYgBYAYgioiHsHBwhwAFoU2IBGAFZYgE4ANjLEwjB-FABJGABRAEdLOFoMAB5UABpkAFVhgE1kAF4tKGjhgDlp5HheiAA+ab4SAAo+gHF1nYBKac395AgAD0gQClVUZAB+ZBLkVljT69v77eI9w4nM7IC7ffL3UbPV7vZCfKGTVgLXgEBpNZBtG5QRBgZyWMBwAS0CADTYzfBEEgAbQAClAqIZkKBkABrCD0LxoAC6zD+yGkACp+bzkPz0Vc4A5DESeRSSKLWp1ur0+jgyJQaAwmMIwBwQJxxMMAErZKhQCh9ADkcAtgxEes2BU2ZDAligIFUqwwEGF-OkvIVXR6-WpbmZA2GtPp6yNJrNfUjhmGqBpdMMnPWmzBdw9Qe9sqhIAgADdoLzWAmJJTWeyYFypOT+I0AsgAMK6bLM5YYnXY3H4wnE9BYTayZAAIgEY4kUns7uwCCJcCgCegYGAmhmO0MqdX64wqCoLcXUFYAEEoFj6H1u1iEDi8QSiQNMGAM8MaAB5AQAK2yYFYQ5gMcAEvmcvLbvSu6YAeR7kFANiKJYSA7DsiAIMMEBEg4pxTJsOwNvwJA2MRaGDMKVKYRADjcuOU75uIxzviAX6-nexwzseK5QGumA7JSFoCBanLDDgWrIFaNqCKwAkWsgDF8nIVDMhxcFcTxGB8RJwm4GJEnDEI4mCXJpyjtAdJQEAA)

Comment: This is impressive :D really useful, thanks for providing this